# How to prevent my code from creating a 'nonetype' variable

Tags: python

These are the codes related to my problem: (Edited for the full codes, I apologize for any confusion caused)

```
class House:
def __init__(self, location, price, housetype, sqft):
    self.location = str(location)
    self.price = float(price)
    self.housetype = str(housetype)
    self.sqft = int(sqft)

    if self.price < 0 or self.sqft < 100:
        print("Input a valid value.")

def getLocation(self):
    return self.location

def getPrice(self):
    return self.price

def getHousetype(self):
    return self.housetype

def getSqft(self):
    return self.sqft

def setLocation(self, newLocation):
    self.location = newLocation

def setPrice(self, newPrice):
    if newPrice > 0:
        self.price = newPrice
    else:
        print("Input a valid value.")

def setHousetype(self, newHousetype):
    self.housetype = newHousetype

def setSqft(self, newSqft):
    if newSqft > 100:
        self.sqft = newSqft
    else:
        print("Input a valid value.")

def tax(self, no_years):
    if self.getHousetype == 'Apartment':
        return self.price * (0.025 * no_years)
    elif self.getHousetype == 'Bungalow':
        return self.price * (0.035 * no_years)
    elif self.getHousetype == 'Condominium':
        return self.price * (0.045 * no_years)
    else:
        print("Invalid data.")

def __eq__ (self, other):
    if self.getHousetype() == other.getHousetype():
        return 'true'
    else:
        return 'false'

def __lt__ (self, no_years, other):
    if self.tax(no_years) < other.tax(no_years):
        return 'true'
```

I created two house variables according to my format, but when I run `house1.__lt__(5, house2)`, it gives me the error:

> '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'.

I have been trying various ways to solve this problem for about an hour, but I'm really new to python and don't know how I can prevent my code from getting these 'NoneType' values, nor can I change them to an integer for my code for the method `__lt__`. Could someone tell me how I can solve this?

Comment: What is `self.getHousetype`? It doesn't match any of your conditions, so the function returns nothing (`None`).

Comment: Return something in an else statement would be a good start

Comment: Is `getHousetype` a function or a property of the class? Note: python doesn't need getter methods

Comment: when we not give any return value to function then function return `None`. In above case, function `tax` have return statement in `if` condition, suppose this condition is not satisfy then function return `None`.  So add `return 0` statement to end of `tax` function.

Comment: Actually I've made the objects house1 and house2 fit one of the 3 house types for testing purposes, and yet I do get the error which I've mentioned. I agree that returning something in an else statement would be good, but it doesn't help with the current problem I am having :(

Comment: A variant on Vivek's suggestion: add an else statement that throws an exception. If you run it again and get an exception instead of a `NoneType` error, you know the problem *is* because none of the conditions matched after all. If you don't, you can update your question and reassure us :-)

Comment: Ohmygawd sorry guys I've added the 'else' in the code and it seems there's something wrong with my 'tax' method to begin with. I sincerely apologize for my stupidity ;-; I'm getting 'Invalid data.' when I run house1.tax(4) after putting in the values: house1 = House('A', 150, 'Bungalow', 500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.getHousetype` on its own is a method object, so `self.getHousetype == 'Apartment'` is always false. You need to call the method, i.e. `self.getHousetype() == 'Apartment'`. Since all your conditions are false at the moment, none of your return statement happens and the function ends by returning the default `None`.

But as cricket_007 pointed out, python has no need for getter methods, so just do `self.housetype == 'Apartment'`

self.housetype

Comment: I'm actually surprised I haven't noticed this earlier ohmygawd.. I think it all works after I added the () at the end of the getter method. The current course I've been enrolled at kinda requires to use getter methods, so I guess I should focus more on not making these kinds of mistakes next time. Sorry for the commotion caused by my lack of understanding!